# Find max width from all span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem statement :

> Actually I have table as you can see in image I want apply width to
>   span dynamically. **because as you can see in image Action label and
>   dimension label are uneven**

[image]

**I want some thing Like this:**

[image]

My dynamic code for table:

See this above result: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/nL1u3rpj/2/

```
$('#someID').html('<table class="chiled-width-100">' +
    '<tr> <td><span>Application:</span><span title ="' + response.appName + '" class="text-bold">' + response.appName + '</span></td>' +
    '<td><span>Status:</span><span class="addErrorClass" title ="' + response.status + '"" class="text-bold">' + response.status + '</span></td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr> <td><span>Dimension:</span><span title="' + response.dimensionName + '" class="text-bold">' + response.dimensionName + '</span></td>' +
    '<td><span>Error Count:</span><span title="' + response.errorCount + '" class="text-bold">' + response.errorCount + '</span></td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr><td><span>Action: </span><span title="' + response.actionName + '" class="text-bold">' + response.actionName + '</span></td>' +
    '<td><span>Message:</span><span title="' + message + '" class="text-bold">' + message + '</span></td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>');
```

If it is possible with css or other solution then also it is ok but i think css is good option  because if I use jquery or javascript then it requires some loop or logic so i tried to find solution using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found css solution.

```
.chiled-width-100 tr td :first-child{
  max-width: 21%;
}
.chiled-width-100 tr td span{
  width: 76%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example :http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/nL1u3rpj/17/

> Note: In my example window size is big so is use max-width 21% in
>   fiddle output scree is small so i used 31% max-width.

Answer (score 1):

Use `each` to loop over `span` and get maxWidth.

```
var maxWidth = 0;
$('table span').each(function () {
    maxWidth = $(this).width() > maxWidth ? $(this).width() : maxWidth;
});
$('table span').width(maxWidth).css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nL1u3rpj/9/

Comment: `inline-block` would be better.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Right!. Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following css to your code

```
.chiled-width-100 tr td span{
    display:block;
    width:45%; /*adjust this accordingly*/
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: if my text increase then it will overlapped http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/nL1u3rpj/10/

Answer (score 0):

Align span elements with CSS float and width property, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/nL1u3rpj/2/)

```
span {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: if my text increase then it will overlapped http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/nL1u3rpj/10/

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code after creating the table
$('&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp').insertBefore("span")

Comment: this is not a solution